# How to retrieve Cognito UserPool attributes using "getUser" React JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

**UPDATE:** FOUND THE ANSWER and made a Video: [AWS Cognito - get authenticated User UserPool Attributes - React.JS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJHeGpe7a70)

I am trying to retrieve the authenticated users user pool attributes so I can display the attribute values like their name, email, phone number, etc.... that they used to sign up.

First, Im wondering if I need to create an API call / Lambda function or if I can simply just use the `import { Auth } from "aws-amplify"`.

For example to log in, I call `await Auth.signIn(fields.email, fields.password);` and that's all I need to log in.

Could I possibly do something similar to get the logged in user attributes like call `await Auth.getUser()` or do I need to create an API call? Im just trying to figure out the most secure way to go about it and the aws amplify docs are not making a ton of sense to me. any help or insight is greatly appreciated!

[AWS AMPLIFY DOCS WORKING WITH ATTRIBUTES](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#working-with-user-attributes)

[AWS getUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html)